# Using search feature in Ionic framework

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-filter-bar

I am a UI person and very new to ionic framework.. I wanted to add search feature in my android app built using Ionic framework. After a research i found that I will need to use this plugin https://github.com/djett41/ionic-filter-bar. but there is no detail documentation available. Can anyone please guide how to use this plugin working. I have made all setup but stuck with actual code.

Comment: This will help you,http://codepen.io/ionic/pen/CrInw

Comment: You need to search from JSON array?

Comment: Did you have the chance to have a look at my answer?

Comment: Hi LeftyX, thanks for your solution! I am working on it.. but somehow when I click on search button, nothing is appearing below.. neither it is showing any error .. I am just trying to figure out that

Comment: Ok! it is showing now! :) there was an issue in controller function and linking.. one thing I missed to mention.. my text is in hindi language.. can you suggest how can I implement that?

Comment: I got stuck on that too. The button icon is now ion-ios7-search-strong or ion-android-search-strong.

Answer (score 12):

First of all you must install the plugin. You can use **bower** for that:

```
bower install ionic-filter-bar --save
```

and it will copy all the `javascript` and `css` needed in the `lib` folder inside `www`.

Then you must add the references to the `css` to your **index.html**:

```
<link href="lib/ionic-filter-bar/dist/ionic.filter.bar.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

same thing for the `javascript`:

```
<script src="lib/ionic-filter-bar/dist/ionic.filter.bar.js"></script>
```

You have to inject the module `jett.ionic.filter.bar` you your main module:

```
var app = angular.module('app', [
        'ionic',
        'jett.ionic.filter.bar'
    ]);
```

and you must reference the service `$ionicFilterBar` in your controller:

```
angular.module('app')
        .controller('home', function($scope, $ionicFilterBar){

    });
```

Now you can start using it.

In my sample I want to trigger the search-box when the user clicks/taps on a icon in the header. I would add this HTML to the view:

```
  <ion-nav-buttons side="secondary">
    <button class="button button-icon icon ion-ios-search-strong" ng-click="showFilterBar()">
    </button>
  </ion-nav-buttons>
```

The action trigger an event in my controller `showFilterBar`:

```
  $scope.showFilterBar = function () {
    var filterBarInstance = $ionicFilterBar.show({
      cancelText: "<i class='ion-ios-close-outline'></i>",
      items: $scope.places,
      update: function (filteredItems, filterText) {
        $scope.places = filteredItems;
      }
    });
  };
```

which creates the `$ionicFilterBar` and shows it.

As you can see here I am using an array of objects `$scope.places`

```
$scope.places = [{name:'New York'}, {name: 'London'}, {name: 'Milan'}, {name:'Paris'}];
```

which I have linked to the `items` member of my `$ionicFilterBar`. The update method will give me in `filteredItems` the items (places) filtered.

You can play with this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/oB4J11YcN9UrlYuCzZ1f?p=preview).

Another option is to use the plugin to actually fetch some data remotely through `$http`.

If we want to achieve this we can use the update function again.
Now we don't need to bind the items to our array of objects cause we won't need the filtered elements.

We will use the `filterText` to perform some action:

```
  $scope.showFilterBar = function () {
    var filterBarInstance = $ionicFilterBar.show({
      cancelText: "<i class='ion-ios-close-outline'></i>",
      // items: $scope.places,
      update: function (filteredItems, filterText) {
        if (filterText) {
            console.log(filterText);
            $scope.fetchPlaces(filterText);
        }
      }
    });
  };
```

We will call another function which will, maybe, call `$http` and return some data which we can bind to our array of objects:

```
 $scope.fetchPlaces = function(searchText)
  {
    $scope.places = <result of $http call>;
  }
```

Another plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ecA2w9194AP2VVskuoDx?p=preview).

PS:

If you want to configure it using some sort of customization you must do it in your configuration using the provider `$ionicFilterBarConfigProvider`:

```
angular.module('app')
    .config(function($ionicFilterBarConfigProvider){
        $ionicFilterBarConfigProvider.clear('ion-ios-close-empty');
    })
```

PPS:

In my plunker I've included the `css` and the `script` directly copying it from the source.

**UPDATE**:

Someone asked not to replace the list with the updated one. 
My cheap and dirty solution is to check if the `filterText` contains some values. If it's empty (no searches) we go throught each element an set a property `found = false` otherwise we compare the `places` array we the `filteredItems` array.
Matching elements will be marked as found.

```
  function allNotFound(filteredItems) {
    angular.forEach($scope.places, function(item){
      item.found = false;
    });
  }

  function matchingItems(filteredItems) {
    angular.forEach($scope.places, function(item){
        var found = $filter('filter')(filteredItems, {name: item.name});
        if (found && found.length > 0) {
            console.log('found', item.name);
            item.found = true;
        } else {
          item.found = false;
          console.log('not found', item.name);
        }
    });
```

and now we can integrate the filter bar this way:

```
 $scope.showFilterBar = function () {
    var filterBarInstance = $ionicFilterBar.show({
      cancelText: "<i class='ion-ios-close-outline'></i>",
      items: $scope.places,
      update: function (filteredItems, filterText) {
          if (!filterText) {
              allNotFound();
          } else {
            matchingItems(filteredItems);
          }
      }
    });
  };
```

We can use the `found` attribute of the object to change the style of the element.

As always, a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/l6RgSYLXYM6kDRD1NlZ9) to show how it works.

Comment: Hi,  I am using my local language (hindi) in app. Can you suggest, how search work with localization?

Comment: I'm getting stuck on... "Unknown provider: $ionicConfigProvider <- $ionicConfig <- $ionicFilterBar"   any advise?

Comment: @LeftyX Thank you for this.That was very clear and helped me a lot !

Comment: @jacquesseite: Glad I've helped. Cheers.

Comment: What If I want full list despite being filtered. 
In my case, I am using filter for UI purpose not to filter the data

Comment: @Navaneeth: I don't understand what you mean. Cheers.

Comment: `$scope.places = filteredItems;` this line replaces the original liston scope, right? If search should update the view but not the original datastructure, what should I do?

Comment: @Navaneeth: you can do plenty of things. This is more like an implementaton issues. Anyway, I can offer my solution. Check the updated answer and this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/l6RgSYLXYM6kDRD1NlZ9). Cheers.

Comment: @LeftyX i want to disable hide feature in filter bar, how to do that. [Docs](https://github.com/djett41/ionic-filter-bar) mentioned "@returns {function} hideFilterBar A function which, when called, hides & cancels the filter bar." but i do not understand how to use that according to my requirements.

Comment: @ImdadAli: I don't quite understand what you mean. Do you want to have the search bar always visible? If that's the case I don't think you can as this widget is meant to work as an overlay, disabling what's underneath. In the docs they are referring to the method [show](https://github.com/djett41/ionic-filter-bar#ionicfilterbarshow) `$ionicFilterBar.show`. That method returns a function you can use to hide the searc bar. Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/yTLLn3069GzKMNq0Sbng?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

Ionic uses Angular, and Angular include an atributte filter very useful. Look this: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter and the example there. Regards